# Passing newline on a javascript page isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, header, textarea, newline

What I'm trying to do is pass a complex text that is including one or more newline chars via URL/GET form. On the other side the parameters I've passed are interpreted by javascript (sort of) and is probably cleaned from any newline or other escaped chars so that it's not working at all, apart from 1 single CASE that I can reproduce but not fully understand.

- If I pass (via PHP header function) on the URL %0D%0A the result on the page is that those chars are filtered and doesn't appear at all in the textarea.
- BUT if I manually write on the address bar the same URL with these chars, the newline is appearing.

I've also tried using a form/GET but the url is encoded and I cannot pass %0D%0A.

Thanks for any kind of help that you can provide on this issue.

Code is something like:

**SOURCE PAGE** (using PHP):

```
... various code preparation ...
header("Location: DESTINATION?a=bbbbbb%0D%0Acccc");
```

**DESTINATION PAGE** (html+javascript):

```
... some javascript function that takes the a parameter from the query string and it's cleaning and putting dinamically into the textarea ...
<textarea>bbbbbbcccc</textarea>
```

I can't access the DESTINATION PAGE (external web application that I don't own and to which I need to pass some text with newslines working

Comment: Got some code for us to look at?

Comment: What are you trying to do?? I mean in the grand scheme of things

Comment: SOURCE PAGE (using PHP): header("Location: DESTINATION?/a=bbbbbb%0D%0Acccc");

DESTINATION PAGE (html+javascript): <textarea>bbbbbbcccc</textarea> ---> The content of the textarea goes through a javascript function that I can't access and is probably filtering the newline

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to change the new lines by br element?

In JavaScript:

```
var str = "My string \n with lines";
str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

If you need it in PHP:

```
$str = "My string \n with lines";
$str = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $str);
```

Comment: I can't access the DESTINATION page (not on my domain, it's an external web application and I need to pass some text with newlines in it. I've tried playing with iFrames but I can't due to XSS protection

Comment: header("Location: DESTINATION?/a=bbbbbb%3Cbr+%2F%3Ecccc") works?

Comment: Why '?/a=value' and not '?a=value'

Comment: on the textarea I'm seeing <br /> but not a newline. It seems to work ONLY with %0A%0D when manually written on the address bar of my browser but NOW when passing using the header call

Comment: What do you see in browser address bar after the redirect to the new location? There is not %0A%0D?

Comment: Yes, the %0A%0D is on the address bar but disappears in the resulting textarea where the text goes. The behavior that I'm trying to track down is that if I delete %0A%0D on the address and write it again manually and send the page again... Well it's working! It accepts newlines. It's like the passed header has some different char in the destination page but I can't see any difference